# shared tcp socket android service

Tags: android, multithreading, networking, tcp

in my android application I will define service to communicate with server.

Question : Can I use same tcp socket in 2 thread's for receiving and sending  data simultaniosly ?

Thanks.

Comment: Were you able to achieve it? I was looking for a way to create 2 threads for the same socket. If you could post your code it would help a lot of people

Answer (score 0):

Two threads can use the same socket so that one thread is only reading from socket and the other only writing. If you try to read and write from both threads you will have conflicts.

Comment: so better to define 2 sockets , one for receive and one to send data ?

Comment: No, using one socket is fine. One thread will be reading data and the other will be writing. This works without any issues.

Comment: so how can I avoid conflicts you menאion above ?

Comment: You will get conflicts if thread A tries to read AND write to/from socket AND thread B tries to read AND write to/from the SAME socket. You will NOT get any conflicts if thread A reads from socket and thread B writes to the same socket.